# How to call with optional params in JS interface for Kotlin

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, web-applications, scripting-bridge

I have a Javascript bridge method in Kotlin like,

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun add(a: Int? = 0, b: Int? = 0): Int {
  return a + b
}
```

If I want to call with default value, how can I call this method from web app js?

```
android.add(null, null) // OR
android.add() // OR
android.add(a = 0, b = 0)// OR
```

Or what?

Comment: If no value is provided, it will use the default value, so android.add() will be fine.

Comment: @Kobe what if I want functioning for something like `android.add(b=5)`? or only with 1st params like `android.add(1)` ? are they allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use default value of parameter `undefined` should be passed as an argument. It could be done like this:

```
android.add() // empty arguments means all of them are undefined so defaults are used
android.add(1) // a == 1, b == undefined so the default value (0) is used
android.add(void 0, 2) // a == undefined and its default (0) is used, b == 2
```

Comment: Thanks Roman. I am still confused for `android.add(void 0, 2)` why default value is provided from caller js side? It's already defined in the native side right? Did you mean `android.add(void, 2)` ?

Comment: If I got you correct `void 0` is just an expression which guaranteed to be `undefined` when `void` is not an expression.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `annotation`

`@JvmOverloads`

This generates overloaded methods in the compiled bytecode for the @JavaScriptInterface.

You can easily then call

`android.add()`

from JS in order to invoke the default arguments for your method,
still keeping your code idiomatic.